# Duda/Problema DNS Windows

Tags: windows, dns, redes

tengo una duda con los DNS de Windows ya que he creado un Servidor Active Directory en ubuntu server el cual la IP es 192.168.1.50 y el dominio qwick.com

Me gustaría unir el cliente Windows al dominio, cuando hago ping a la IP del servidor SI da respuesta pero cuando lo hago a el dominio no da respuesta.

Tengo en la configuración de red puesto como único DNS la IP del servidor pero cuando hago un ipconfig/all me salen varios DNS que ni entiendo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver tengo 5 DNS mas aparte del 192.168.1.50, me gustaría saber como quitarlo y hacer que me haga un ping a el dominio qwick.com